# Trouble having EMA script trade properly

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script and coding in general and I am trying to code what I thought would be an easy strategy. I'd like it to buy when the last candle closes above the EMA, and sell when the last candle closes below the EMA. Additionally, I would like to see what it would do if it would buy when the last 2 candles close above the EMA, and sell when the last 2 candles close below the EMA.
Here is my code so far:

```
strategy("9EMA", overlay=true, calc_on_order_fills=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)
//EMA
ema = ema(close, 9)
plot(ema, "EMA", color=color.yellow)
if crossover(close, ema) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
if crossunder(close, ema) 
    strategy.close("Long", comment="sell")
```

It's buying and selling simultaneously as well as buying/selling when the previous candle does not meet the requirement to make an order.
Any help/tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//@version=4
strategy("9EMA", overlay=true, calc_on_order_fills=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)
//EMA

ema = ema(close, 9)
plot(ema, "EMA", color=color.yellow)


buyCondition = crossover(close, ema)[2] and close[1]>ema and close>ema
sellCondition = crossunder(close, ema)[2] and close[1]<ema and close<ema

if  buyCondition   
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Buy")

if sellCondition   
    strategy.close("Long", comment="sell")
    

bgcolor( crossover(close, ema)? color.green:na)
bgcolor( crossunder(close, ema)? color.red:na)
```

Comment: This works thank you! But could you explain the [2] and [1] you included in this?

Comment: This is a history referencing operator.  It allows you to refer to the past values from the chart. Learn more here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator